# Objects detection in an image

Tags: opencv, image-processing

Need some guidance here, I'm trying to identify different objects in an image and get their bounding box.

The image is always clean with transparent background and well separated objects.

[image: example image]

for example in the above image there are 3 objects. Any idea or any tool would be helpful.

Comment: A [link](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/shapedescriptors/bounding_rects_circles/bounding_rects_circles.html) to get you started..

Comment: You can't get bounding boxes with it, but Clarifai's API might be able to help you with the actual identification process: clarifai.com

Answer (score 0):

As the objects are on such background, a simple connected components labeling will give you a first basic answer. However, it will be more complicated to find out which objects are overlapping.

Do you have any information about the objects to detect?

Comment: Thanks, connected components labeling seems like the thing I was looking for. I don't need to identify objects overlapping, if they count as one objects that's ok.

Comment: Then, don't do anything more complicated. A connected component labeling will do exactly what you need. You will have one different value for each object.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the template matching to find the flowers and the top-right object (assuming here that they are similar) given the image of the flower (as a template) and the whole picture.

There is an example of the template detection [here](http://opencv-code.com/quick-tips/how-to-handle-template-matching-with-multiple-occurences/): (where reference.png is the original image, and the template.png is the object you want to detect, like the flower)

Here is an image of the flower (renamed to template.png):

[image]

Running the template matching code with the whole image as reference.png, we can find the flowers (highlighted in green rectangles):

[image]

Although the code did not implement the bounding boxes, you can use `boundingRect()` to draw a minimum bounding rectangle (given a single contour).

The outline may be something like:

1. Set a ROI (Region of Interest) inside each of the green boxes.
2. Find the contours of pink objects.
3. Use `boundingRect` on the contours found, and draw the minimum rectangle around the flower.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. In my case I don't have any particular template I can use, the example image actually demonstrate that there are 3 objects, 2 of them are completely different but they all can be different.